# Recursive Selection Sort in Java

Tags: java, sorting, recursion, arraylist, selection-sort

I need to implement this algorithm creating a new ArrayList object at each recursive call.

My starting Array contains integers in this order"20, 40 ,10, 30 ,50 ,5" , after sorting it I have `5,5,5,5,5,5`. I think that the problem is in the recursive call and in the last for cicle of the `SelectionSort` because removing the last for I notice that the the first element is sorted correctly.

```
import java.util.*;

public class SelectionSort {

   //var
   public ArrayList<Integer> arr ;

   //constructor
   public SelectionSort(ArrayList<Integer> arr){
      this.arr = arr;
   }

   public ArrayList<Integer> getarraylist() {
   return arr;
   }


   public void sort(){  

     //position of the last sorted element
     int minimum =0;

     if (arr.size() <=0 )  return;

     for ( int j = 1; j < arr.size()-1; j++ ) { 

           if (arr.get(j) < arr.get(0) ) {
               minimum = j;
               //swap element 0 and minimum
               int temp = arr.get(0);
               arr.set(0, arr.get(minimum));
               arr.set(minimum, temp);
           }
     }

     //recursive call, new array without first element (already sorted)
     ArrayList<Integer> arr2 = new ArrayList<>(arr.subList(1,arr.size()));
     SelectionSort s2 = new SelectionSort(arr2);
     s2.sort();

     for(int i=0;i<s2.getarraylist().size();i++) {
         arr.set(i, s2.getarraylist().get(i));
     }
}
```

Driver class

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer (Arrays.asList(20,40,10,30,50,5));


    System.out.println("\n ARRAY ELEMENTS \n ");
    for (int i: arr) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }

    System.out.println("\n SORTED ELEMENTS \n ");
    SelectionSort s = new SelectionSort(arr);
    s.sort();
    for (int i: s.getarraylist()) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Please see: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Could you please give an example input/output to illustrate how it's sorting incorrectly?

Comment: Thanks @GBlodgett My starting Array contains integers in this order"20, 40 ,10, 30 ,50 ,5" , after sorting it I have "5,5,5,5,5,5" I think that the problem is in the last for cicle of the "SelectionSort" class

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add this information.

Comment: @Turing85 I don't know why your last reply about the "set" method seems disappeared. Anyway Eclipse report this about that method : "replace the element at the specified position in this list with the specified element"

Comment: yeah, it was XD. No problem bro, thanks anyway for trying to help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have actually two bugs in your algorithm that, together, lead to the observed output.

---

The first bug is within the `for`-loop that determines the minimal element:

```
for ( int j = 1; j < arr.size()-1; j++ ) { ...
```

You terminate one element too early, i.e. the last element is never considered. Thus, after the first iteration, the `5` is the last element in your `ArrayList`. In fact, it is the last element in *every* of your `ArrayList`s. The fix is to not subtract `1` in the `for`-condition:

```
for ( int j = 1; j < arr.size(); j++ ) { ...
```

---

The second bug is in your last `for`-loop where you copy the values from index `i` of `s2` to index `i` of `arr`. You neglect the fact that `s2` is one element shorter than `arr`. Thus, the only element not overriden is the last element. The fix is to get the `i`-th element from `s2`, but write it at the `i + 1`-th index of `arr`:

```
arr.set(i + 1, s2.getarraylist().get(i));
```

---

Now let us take look at how those two bugs lead to the observed output. Since

- the last element in your `ArrayList` is never overridden and
- the last element is always the same,

all elements have the same value (in your test case: `5`).

---

Some remarks on your code:

- the variable `minimum` is superfluous and can be replaced with `j`.
- If you replace all occurences of `ArrayList` in `SelectionSort` with `List`, you can actually simplify the last part of your code to:

  ```
  // remove the line declaring arr2, it is no longer needed
  SelectionSort s2 = new SelectionSort(arr.subList(1, arr.size()));
  s2.sort();
  // last for-loop not needed anymore, method ends here
  ```

  This is possible because [`ArrayList#subList(...)` states that "*The returned list is backed by this list, so non-structural changes in the returned list are reflected in this list, and vice-versa.*"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#subList(int,int))
- You should take a little bit more care wrt. indentation.
- You have some minor inconsistencies in your coding style. For example, sometimes you write a blank after `(` or before a `)` or `{`, sometimes you do not. See what you like more and use it uniformly.
- In Java, variable-, parameter- and methodnames should be written in [camelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) (`getarraylist()` -> `getArrayList()`)

Comment: Yes! Many many thanks for the help! Next thing I will do is to do the same with the Insertion Sort (I hope to avoid errors XD) Thanks also for your remarks, I' ll try to be more accurate next time :)

Answer (score 1):

With your last loop:

```
for(int i=0;i<s2.getarraylist().size();i++) {
     arr.set(i, s2.getarraylist().get(i));
 }
```

This overrides every element with the same number. (Why you got all 5's as your result) This is because you only iterate to the second to last element (`arr.size()-1`). Then you copy the elements in the line:

```
 ArrayList<Integer> arr2 = new ArrayList<>(arr.subList(1,arr.size()));
```

Eventually you are only copying the last element over (5) and then copying this to the final `ArrayList` `arr`.

Also you create another `SelectionSort` object every time you call the `sort` method. This is not good.

Here is the code I wrote:

```
 public void sort(List<Integer> list){  

     //position of the last ordered element
     int minimum =0;
     if (list.size() <=0 )  return;

     for ( int j = 1; j < list.size(); j++ ) { 

           if (list.get(j) < list.get(0) ) {
               minimum = j;
               //swap element 0 and minimum
               int temp = list.get(0);
               list.set(0, list.get(minimum));
               list.set(minimum, temp);

           }

     }


     sort(list.subList(1,list.size()));
}
```

I changed it to accept an argument of `List<Integer>` (Because the `subList()` method returns a `List`) and then got rid of the last loop and where you created new objects.

Also youll have to change

```
s.sort();
```

to:

```
s.sort(s.getarraylist());
```

Output:

```
 ARRAY ELEMENTS 

20
40
10
30
50
5

 SORTED ELEMENTS 

5
10
20
30
40
50
```

Comment: "*This overrides every element with the same number.*" - Can you elaborate? Since OP uses `i` for the `get(...)` and `set(...)` (`arr.set(i, s2.getarraylist().get(i));`), this claim is not obvious.

Comment: @Turing85 I edited my question but +1 from me on your better explanation

Comment: One point: don't make the `ArrayList` static. This can lead to nasty bugs and is a pain to test/mock.

Comment: @GBlodgett Thanks for the code. I made the algorithm also in a way similar to the one you proposed (instead of the araylist I used an integer as parameter of the sort method and it works)Anyway I wan to find a solution to this problem in particular. I removed the last "for" and I noticed that the 1st element it's correctly sorted so the problem it's just in the recursive call and in the last "for"

Comment: @Turing85 Hmm hadn't considered that. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure I understand the question, but I created a recursive (and iterative) selectionSort and InsertionSort just for fun, hope it helps.

```
public class Sorts {
    public static void swap(Comparable[] a, int i, int j) {
        Comparable temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = temp;
    }

    public static void selectionSortItr(Comparable[] a, int n) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
            int f = i;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
                if (a[j].compareTo(a[f]) < 0)
                    f = j;
            }
            swap(a, i, f);
        }
    }

    public static int select(Comparable[] a, int n, int j, int f) {
        if (j >= n) 
            return f;
        if (a[j].compareTo(a[f]) < 0)
            f = j;
        return select(a, n, j + 1, f);
    }

    public static void selectionSort(Comparable[] a, int n, int i) {
        if (i < n - 1) {
            swap(a, i, select(a, n, i + 1, i));
            selectionSort(a, n, i + 1);
        }
    }

    public static void insertionSortItr(Comparable[] a) {
        for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
            int j;
            Comparable cur = a[i];
            for (j = i; j > 0 && cur.compareTo(a[j - 1]) < 0; j--) {
                a[j] = a[j - 1];
            }
            a[j] = cur;
        }
    }

    public static void insertionSortInner(Comparable[] a, Comparable cur, int j) {
        if (j > 0 && cur.compareTo(a[j - 1]) < 0) {
            a[j] = a[j - 1];
            insertionSortInner(a, cur, j - 1);
        } else {
            a[j] = cur;
        }
    }

    public static void insertionSort(Comparable[] a, int i, int n) {
        if (i < n) {
            insertionSortInner(a, a[i], i);
            insertionSort(a, i + 1, n);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] a = new Integer[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
            a[i] = (int) (Math.random()*100);
        selectionSort(a, 10, 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
            System.out.println(a[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I just realized this is InsertionSort, not SelectionSort. I apologize for that... ;)